# How to use imageio imread to get a multi channel array (RGB) from a single channel image (grayscale)?

Tags: python, python-imageio

So I want to use imageio to read a black-and-white image as a 3d image.
If I had used opencv I would use the following command since opencv's default is IMREAD_COLOR:
`im3d = cv2.imread(im_path)`
This results in shape (186, 148, 3)

However, since it is a black-and-white image, imageio contrary to opencv defaults to reading two dimensions. Thus
`im3d = imageio.imread(im_path)`
results in shape (186, 148).

According to the imageio docs, I need to add "format", a string with "The format to use to read the file." to make imageio behave the way I want to. See this link:
https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.imread

But this is so badly explained! I am often amazed by how bad documentation is.
I have no way to know what to enter as "format" in order to get imageio to behave as I want.
So any help on this would be very appreciated!

Comment: what is the format of your image file?

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation link you provided, you can see a navigation item [`Docs for the formats`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats.html) quite prominent on the left side. For example, let's check the [PNG format](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_png-pil.html#png-pil) entry, since PNG supports single channel images. There's a section [Parameters for reading](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_png-pil.html#parameters-for-reading): You need to provide a proper Pillow format string, for RGB images, it's `'RGB'`. The parameter to be used is called `pilmode`. Let's check that:

```py
import imageio

im = imageio.imread('path/to/some/singlechannelimage.png')
print(im.shape)

im3d = imageio.imread('path/to/some/singlechannelimage.png', pilmode='RGB')
print(im3d.shape)
```

If I run that for some single channel PNG, I get:

```
(639, 379)
(639, 379, 3)
```

That's what you want, I suppose.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
imageio:       2.9.0
----------------------------------------
```